# Calculating the length of the network lines inside polygon in QGIS 2.10.1

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, length, qgis-2.10

I am working with 2 datasets:

- delineations of the neighbourhoods
- traffic network.

This is how they look:

[image]

I would like to calculate the length of the roads per neighbourhood (polygon). As you may expect some of the roads are in more than one neighbourhood so what I have to do first is "cutting" them at point where they are crossing with polygon boundaries. I have tried to use intersect tool but it did not work. I always got empty file as an output. The projection I am using is RD New (for both files) so it should work. Any ideas how can I achieve my goal?

When I have roads cut I would calculate the length of every line and afterwards  sum these lengths up per neighbourhood. Is it a good way to do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Give the Sum Line Lengths tool a try, from the Vector > Analysis Tools menu:

[image]

This will create a new shapefile that summarizes each **input polygon vector layer** feature by the length of **input line vector layer**.

The output shapefile should have an attribute field called **LENGTH** as you can see in the above screenshot, but you can change that to SUM_LENGTH or something similar.

Then you can visualize your map on that field, if that is your purpose:

[image]

**NOTE** the units are important to your inputs, so in my example decimal degrees are not too meaningful...but if your input coordinate system is in metres you should be good.

Comment: I have tried it before (I forgot to mention that) and all obtained lengths were 0.00000. I have tried it once more and I have got the same results. Maybe I should consider that the problem lies in data, not in tools used... Anyway, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: I tried to use another polygon file and it worked! So the neighbourhood dataset caused all my troubles. I should think about it earlier!

Comment: This is a very helpful answer. Thank you very much!