# Calculating the length of lines within polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm seeking to calculate the length of all street/highway segments in New York City that are within 400 feet of a school. In QGIS, I have a line layer that is all the streets/highways in the city, and a polygon layer that is dissolved 400-foot buffers around every school in the city.

I followed the advice given in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166338/calculating-the-length-of-the-network-lines-inside-polygon-in-qgis-2-10-1) previous thread and used the Sum Line Length tool.

[image]

It produced another layer whose attribute table includes a length number that seems plausible: 569.26 miles (compared to 7,035.01 total miles in the city). However, the new layer consists only of the existing school buffer layer (and shows up as a single row in the attribute table), so I can't actually verify that the line segments QGIS measured to produce that 569 number are in fact the segments within the buffered areas.

[image]

Could anyone confirm that my approach described above would correctly produce the result I'm seeking? Or does anyone know how I could verify it myself? Or if there's a better way to do this?

P.S. I've also used the Sum Line Length tool on a layer of undissolved school buffers, but because of the way the data is structured it's not possible to measure the length of the line segments within the buffers.

P.P.S. Previously I tried using the Extract By Location tool, but "intersects" was returning the length of the entire lines that crossed the buffers, not just the sections within the buffers. And "cross" was taking astronomically long to run.

Comment: If you clip your lines using your polygon buffers, and recalculate any length fields, you should get what you need.

Comment: @johns brilliant! that did it. thanks